# Abnormal DNS output

Tags: dns, vpn, resolv.conf

Why does dnsleaktest.com find previous DNS address/multiple new DNS addresses?

Now I decided to try a new one and to my surprise the dnsleaktest.com gives me three diferent outputs as I check my DNS - most frequently appears only random server.

Comment: ProtonVPN are doing their own DNS leak prevention, are you sure you are not colliding with that?

Comment: @logounk What browser you use? If it's Firefox, then Firefox uses Cloudflare for `DNS over HTTPS` in the US (maybe few other places too): `https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https`